# Restrict user to create a group in case of a conflict

Tags: java, algorithm

I am creating new groups for employees based on a set of optional parameters. Lets say we have 3 parameters - Grade(G1, G2, G3), Band(B1, B2, B3) and Location(L1, L2, L3, L4) and below are the existing groups in the system:

- Group 1: G1, B1, B2, L1, L2, L3
- Group 2: G2, B3, L3
- Group 3: G3, B1, B2, B3, L1, L2, L3

Now when I try to create another group where the parameter conflicts with the existing groups, i.e. if I try to create a new group with any of the grades, the system should not allow as all the 3 grades have been consumed in all the 3 groups. What should be the approach to stop the system from creating a new group when there is a conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my understanding, one would need to create a list of all parameters (perhaps grouped by type, if desired) which are already used. Each parameter used in the new group must not be contained in the list, otherwise the newly created group is to be rejected.